# Gmail SMTP using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

I am using the the following settings for Gmail SMTP mail sending using CodeIgniter mail class library: ![gmail settings][1]

```
Mail Server* :  smtp.gmail.com
Username* : my@gmail.com
Password* : **********
Port* : 567
SMTP_crypto* : TLS
From Address* : my@gmail.com
Reply To* : my@gmail.com
```

But its giving me the following error:

> > The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command.
> >     Error:  Unable to send data: MAIL FROM: from:  The following SMTP
> >     error was encountered:  Unable to send data: RCPT TO: to:  The
> >     following SMTP error was encountered:  Unable to send data: DATA data:
> >     The following SMTP error was encountered:  Unable to send data:
> >     User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Tue, 11 Nov 2014 12:11:22 +0300 From:
> >     "GALTech Staffs" Return-Path: Reply-To: "GALTech Staffs" To:
> >     xxxx@gmail.com Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Hello_Reena?= X-Sender:
> >     xxxx@gmail.com X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 1 (Highest)
> >     Message-ID: <5461d2baf3ee2@gmail.com> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type:
> >     text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
> >     Copyright © 2014 Mailing System, All rights reserved.
>
> Unable to send data: .
>
> The following SMTP error was encountered:  Unable to send email using
>   PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this
>   method. User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Tue, 11 Nov 2014 12:11:22 +0300
>   From: "GALTech Staffs"  Return-Path:  Reply-To: "GALTech Staffs"  To:
>   xxxx@gmail.com Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Hello_Reena?= X-Sender:
>   xxxx@gmail.com X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 1 (Highest)
>   Message-ID: <5461d2baf3ee2@gmail.com> Mime-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding:
>   quoted-printable
>
> Hello
>   Reena
>
> Copyright © 2014 Mailing System, All rights
>   reserved.

Comment: Gmail uses outgoing smtp port 587 for tls connection.

Answer (score 0):

Use port 587 in combination with TLS or port 465 with SSL.

Comment: Gmail is preventing access to using its smtp. But even if I enable settings in this page : https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha its not working.

Comment: Maybe you still have to change the IMAP settings (I know it may sounds odd to have this actived for SMTP): log into your Gmail or Google Apps email Settings and:
Click on the Forwarding/IMAP tab and scroll down to the IMAP Access section: IMAP must be enabled.

Comment: There is something wrong in the code. I tried using other code and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a function to send mail :
Hope it works!

```
$config = array(
                        'protocol' => 'smtp',
                        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                        'smtp_port' => 465,
                        'smtp_user' => 'abc@gmail.com', 
                        'smtp_pass' => 'abcd',
                                        );

                        $message = 'Your mail message here.';
                        $this->load->library('email', $config);
                        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
                        $this->email->clear();
                        $this->email->from('abc@gmail.com');
                        $this->email->to('abc@gmail.com');   //To whom you are sending.
                        $this->email->subject('Your mail subject');
                        $this->email->message($message);
                        if($this->email->send())
                                 {
                                    return true;
                                 }
                                    else
                                 {
                                    return false;
                                 }  

                             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a library coding error. I have fixed it using the following link:
https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer